# Find the names of all students who are enrolled in both A and B classes

Tags: sql

Based on the schema below where

The primary keys are **sid and cid**. And the table schema is below.

- Students (sid: integer, name: string, major: string, age: integer)
- Enrollment (sid: integer, cid: integer)
- Classes (cid: integer, name: string, instructor: string, room: string, time: time)

A student would be listed in the table enrollment with a **sid and cid** and the student will also be listed in the student table with the same **sid**. The **cid** will come from the Classes table.

I am having trouble finding the names of all students who are enrolled in both ‘A’ and 'B' classes. Where A & B is a string for the class name.

```
SELECT S.name FROM Students S JOIN Classes C JOIN Enrollment E ON C.name = "A" AND C.name = "B"
```

Comment: Where are your `ON` clauses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT Sid, S.name
FROM Students S JOIN
     Enrollment E
     USING (sid) JOIN
     Classes C
     USING (cid)
WHERE C.name IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY sid, S.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;   -- "2" is the number of classes in the `IN` list
```

Notes:

- You need `ON` or `USING` clauses for your joins.
- String constants should use single quotes, not double quotes.
- This assumes that a student is not enrolled for the same class more than once.  If that is possible, then use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.name) = 2`.

EDIT:

For "A" and not "B", you can do:

```
HAVING MIN(c.name) = 'A' and MIN(c.name) = MAX(c.name)
```

Comment: isn't intersect more efficient ?

Comment: Probably not, but it is worth comparing both methods.  `INTERSECT` has overhead for removing duplicates, which is essentially a `GROUP BY`.  Plus it is doing the `JOIN`s multiple times.

Comment: Fair point. I always had a good opinion about set operations in sql. But in the end I guess the explain plan has the last word

Comment: Excellent answer @GordonLinoff, the only issue is this has an error for sid for Classes, not present sid.

Comment: @Raymond . . . Oops.  The order in the `from` was wrong.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Prime quality answer to be honest, thanks a lot.

Comment: @GordonLinoff For having A AND B classes, your SQL statement works really well. If I wanted to have for A and NOT IN B, should I just add the NOT IN to the end? Thanks again.

Comment: @Raymond . . . One of the reasons why I like using `HAVING` for this purpose is because it is easy to express a broad range of questions.  I called these "set-within-a-set" queries.

Comment: @Raymond: And you can also check individually in the `HAVING` clause with conditional aggregation. E.g.: `having max(case when c.name = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and max(case when c.name = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) = 0`.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT S.name FROM Students S 
JOIN Enrollment E ON S.sid=E.sid
JOIN Classes C ON C.cid=E.cid
WHERE C.name = 'A' 
INTERSECT 
SELECT S.name FROM Students S 
JOIN Enrollment E ON S.sid=E.sid
JOIN Classes C ON C.cid=E.cid
WHERE C.name = 'B'
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't join at all. You want rows from the students table, so select `FROM students`. You want a condition met, so use `WHERE`. As for looking up data in other tables, you can use `IN` or `EXISTS`.

```
select name 
from students
where sid in
(
  select sid from enrollment where cid = (select cid from classes where name = 'A')
)
and sid in
(
  select sid from enrollment where cid = (select cid from classes where name = 'B')
)
order by name;
```

Comment: This is a good answer also, I read your statements. Thanks for the support and alternative method.